# JAVA Date Exception?

Tags: java, mysql, date

Ok so i have a class called DepositsBean

```
package Beans;

import java.util.Date;

public class DepositsBean {
private long deposit_id;
private long client_id;
private double balance;
public enum Type {SHORT,LONG}
private long estimated_balance;
private java.sql.Date opening_date;
private java.sql.Date closing_date;
public DepositsBean() {
    super();
}
public Type type;


public long getDeposit_id() {
    return deposit_id;
}
public Type getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(Type type) {
    this.type = type;
}
public void setDeposit_id(long deposit_id) {
    this.deposit_id = deposit_id;
}
public long getClient_id() {
    return client_id;
}
public void setClient_id(long client_id) {
    this.client_id = client_id;
}
public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}
public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}
public long getEstimated_balance() {
    return estimated_balance;
}
public void setEstimated_balance(long estimated_balance) {
    this.estimated_balance = estimated_balance;
}
public java.sql.Date getOpening_date() {
    return opening_date;
}
public void setOpening_date(Date opening_date) {
    this.opening_date = (java.sql.Date) opening_date;
}
public java.sql.Date getClosing_date() {
    return closing_date;
}
public void setClosing_date(Date closing_date) {
    this.closing_date = (java.sql.Date) closing_date;
}

}
```

Got his manager :

```
package Managers;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import Beans.DepositsBean;
import Beans.DepositsBean.Type;

public class DepositsManager implements IDepositsManager {
private ConnectionPool connect;

public DepositsManager(ConnectionPool connect) {
    this.connect = connect;
}

@Override
public void createNewDeposit(DepositsBean deposit,long clientId,double balance) {

    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = connect.connectionCheck().prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO mbank.deposits VALUES"+
                "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setLong(1, deposit.getDeposit_id());
        ps.setLong(2,clientId);
        ps.setDouble(3, balance);
        String type= "";
        if (deposit.getType()==Type.SHORT) {
            type = Type.SHORT.name();
        } else {
            type = Type.LONG.name();
        }
        ps.setString(4, type);
        ps.setLong(5, deposit.getEstimated_balance());
        ps.setDate(6,deposit.getOpening_date());
        ps.setDate(7, (Date) deposit.getClosing_date());
        ps.execute();   


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Problem occurs during creation
                    new deposit");
    }   
}


@Override
public void closeDeposit(long depositId , long accountId ) {

    try{
        PreparedStatement ps = 
                    connect.connectionCheck().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM 
                    mbank.deposits  WHERE deposit_id = ?");
        ps.setLong(1, depositId);  
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        double depositBalance = rs.getDouble("balance");
        Date closingDate = rs.getDate("closing_date");
        java.util.Date currentDate = new java.util.Date();      
        if(currentDate.after(closingDate)){

            PreparedStatement ps1 = 
                           connect.connectionCheck().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM 
                            mbank.accounts WHERE account_id = ?");
            ps1.setLong(1, accountId);  
            ResultSet rs2 = ps1.executeQuery();
            double AccountBalance = rs2.getDouble("balance");

            PreparedStatement ps2 =
                            connect.connectionCheck().prepareStatement(
                    "UPDATE mbank.accounts SET balance = ?" +
                    "WHERE client_id=?");
            ps2.setDouble(1,AccountBalance+depositBalance);
            ps2.executeUpdate();


            PreparedStatement ps3 =  
                            connect.connectionCheck().prepareStatement(
                    "DELETE FROM mbank.deposits WHERE"+
                    "(?)");
            ps3.setLong(1,depositId );
            ps3.execute();
        }


    }catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Problem occurs during the closing the deposit");
    }       


}

@Override
public void preOpenDeposit(long accountId,long depositId) {

    try{
    PreparedStatement ps = connect.connectionCheck().prepareStatement("SELECT *
            FROM mbank.deposits WHERE deposit_id = ?");
    ps.setLong(1, depositId);  
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    double depositBalance = rs.getDouble("balance");
    depositBalance=depositBalance*(PropertiesManager.PRE_OPEN_FEE);


    PreparedStatement ps1 = connect.connectionCheck().prepareStatement("SELECT *    
            FROM mbank.accounts WHERE account_id = ?");
    ps1.setLong(1, accountId);  
    ResultSet rs2 = ps1.executeQuery();
    double AccountBalance = rs2.getDouble("balance");

    PreparedStatement ps2 = connect.connectionCheck().prepareStatement(
            "UPDATE mbank.accounts SET balance = ?" +
            "WHERE client_id=?");
    ps2.setDouble(1,AccountBalance+depositBalance);
    ps2.executeUpdate();


    PreparedStatement ps3 = connect.connectionCheck().prepareStatement(
            "DELETE FROM mbank.deposits WHERE"+
            "(?,?)");
    ps3.setLong(1,depositId );
    ps3.execute();

    }catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Problem occurs during the closing the deposit");
    }       


}


@Override
public void viewAllDeposits() {
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps =    
   connect.connectionCheck().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM mbank.deposits");  
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        String result=null;
        while (rs.next()) {
long deposit_id = rs.getLong("deposit_id");
long client_id = rs.getLong("client_id");
double balance = rs.getDouble("balance");
String type = rs.getString("deposit_type");
long estimated_balance = rs.getLong("estimated_balance");
Date opening_date = rs.getDate("opening_date");
Date closing_date = rs.getDate("closing_date");           
    result = "Client id : " +client_id +"\n" + "deposit id : "  +type +"\n" +"balance:"            
    + balance +"\n" + "deposit type : " +deposit_id +"\n" + "estimated balance : "
    +estimated_balance +"\n" + "closing date : " +closing_date +"\n" + "opening date : "
    +opening_date +"\n"; 
System.out.println(result);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
        "Problem occurs while trying to retrive all clients");
    }

}



}
```

And his interface :

```
package Managers;

import Beans.DepositsBean;

public interface IDepositsManager {

public void createNewDeposit(DepositsBean deposit,long clientId,double 
    balance);//Creating a deposit for X amount of time , taking the money for it from 
    the account
public void closeDeposit(long depositId , long accountId); // Closing the deposit 
    for its time is due 
public void preOpenDeposit(long accountId,long depositId); // Pre opening the 
    deposit - transferring the amount to the account after taking the pre-open fee 
public void viewAllDeposits();
}
```

and the main I am using :

```
import java.sql.Date;

import Action.Action;
import Action.AdminAction;
import Action.ClientAction;
import Beans.AccountsBean;
import Beans.ClientsBean;
import Beans.DepositsBean;
import Beans.DepositsBean.Type;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClientsBean client = new ClientsBean();
    client.setClient_id(227715);

    double balance=2981000;

    java.util.Date currentDate = new java.util.Date();  
    DepositsBean deposit=new DepositsBean();
    deposit.setDeposit_id(1);
    deposit.setClient_id(client.getClient_id());
    deposit.setBalance(100);
    double amount = deposit.getBalance();
    deposit.setType(Type.SHORT);
    deposit.setEstimated_balance(150); 
    deposit.setOpening_date(currentDate);
    deposit.setClosing_date(currentDate);

    ClientAction C = new ClientAction();
    C.createNewDeposit(deposit, client.getClient_id(), amount);
    C.viewClientDeposit(client.getClient_id());
    }
}
```

When I run it i get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date    at
>   Beans.DepositsBean.setOpening_date(DepositsBean.java:53)  at
>   Main.main(Main.java:46)

What I wanted to do is to chack what date is today, and what date was the deposit supose to open. so I'll know if its time to open the deposit or not.
seems like I have a problem with the date here.

Comment: java.sql.Date extends java.util.Date, so you can use a java.sql.Date everywhere java.util.Date is expected. The opposite won't work!

Comment: When applying the date to the SQL statement, wrap it in a java.sql.Date instance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use `java.sql.Date` in your Bean, use only `java.util.Date`, which is the supertype of that one.

When you need to inform some parameter to a JDBC query / procedure call / etc., that is (AFAIK) the only place you will need a `java.sql.Date`, and the best idea is to build it right there.  For example:

```
java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();

Statement stmt = ....;

...

stmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());
```

And then, just forget about `java.sql.Date` unless you are very sure about what you are doing.